# How to display data inside a textbox?

Tags: c#

My question is that I have extracted data from a file and pushed into a string variable.

I have a FORM created in visual studio having a text box, so I want to display that extracted data in textbox created.

How can achieve this?

Comment: where to pass the string variable to display ??should i pass it to textbox function...if yes it says ti cannot be overrided...then how to pass the string inside that function.

Comment: Sorry its not override ...its overloaded

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = yourString;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a TextBox, it is just

```
myTextBox.Text = myStringVariable;
```

But if the data is large, you may want to consider the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control instead.

This is all assuming you're using Windows Forms...

Answer (score 0):

```
string strName="someone";
TextBox1.Text=strName;
```

If you trim the data to remove the unwanted trailing spaces if there is any.

```
TextBox1.Text=strName.Trim();
```